# How to get WPF ListBox to update at start using ItemsSource?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am very new to WPF and especially to data-binding but I'm trying to populate a ListBox with elements from an external resource, and trying to also follow the MVVM pattern. As such I am trying to avoid any code in my code-behind. I've looked over dozens of other questions similar to this but I feel I am missing something stupid as I cannot get my ListBox to generate with values. I have set the DataContext and then set the Binding for the ItemsSource to the correct property.

**Question**

How do I simply get this code to populate my empty ListBox when the application starts up?

**XAML**

```
<TabItem Name="ServerListTab" Header="Server List">
    <TabItem.DataContext>
        <viewModel:ServerListViewModel />
    </TabItem.DataContext>
    <ListBox 
        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
        VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
        ItemsSource="{Binding ServerList, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
        IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" 
        SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedServer}">
    </ListBox>
</TabItem>
```

**ServerList property in view model**

```
public BindingList<string> ServerList
{
    get { return _serverListModel.ServerList; }
    set
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(_serverListModel.ServerList, value)) return;
        var aTestServers = //code hidden : gets array correctly from resource
        for (var i = 0; i < aTestServers.Count; i++)
        {
            _serverListModel.ServerList.Add(aTestServers[i]);
        }
        InvokePropertyChanged("ServerList");
    }
}
```

Comment: Where do you instantiate and initialize _serverListModel.ServerList?
In your constructor, you need to initialize the property so that the property changed notification is invoked.  Otherwise, instantiate the _serverListModel.ServerList object with a valid value in the constructor.

Comment: Oh duh, I simply wasn't doing that...I think I figured it out for now thanks

Comment: As a note, both `Mode=OneWay` and `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` don't make sense on the ItemsSource binding. The binding is one-way by default, and UpdateSourceTrigger is only relevant for two-way or one-way-to-source bindings.

Comment: You shouldn't set the DataContext on individual controls unless you have a really, really good reason to (this isn't one). Set a single DataContext for the view.

Comment: @SledgeHammer how come? I haven't seen anyone else doing this so I assumed it wasn't a good practice haha but haven't seen anything against it until now.

Comment: @CBrown77, it messes up your ability to bind to stuff. Not that you are in your example, but you couldn't bind to a TabItem property without using RelativeSource binding now. A view should typically have a single VM. You are using a tab control though, and in that case, it is acceptable to break out each tab into a user control if they are complicated, but they would be self contained and have thier own VMs (and the view would still have a single context). If they are not too complicated, you'd have the same VM for all tabs and just set the DataContext on the view and it would propogate down.